# When are AD services ready?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, active-directory, windows-services

I have a Windows service running as LocalSystem that depends on Active Directory. After a computer restart, the AD name isn't always immediately available on the server where the service is running when the service starts. For instance, this throws an exception:

```
var ADName = System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetComputerDomain().Name
```

If I make the call 30 seconds later, it does not throw an exception but correctly returns the AD domain name.

If at the same time the exception is thrown I use other APIs, they succeed (for instance):

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName
```

Or use interop:

```
[DllImport("Netapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int NetGetJoinInformation(string server, out IntPtr domain, out NetJoinStatus status);
```

The `NetGetJoinInformation()` gives the NetBIOS domain name, but not the full. But, it at least succeeds without error.

Currently I configure the service to only be dependent on the following services: `Netlogon`. At one point I remember trying others, but had some difficulty, so I wanted to wait until at least Netlogon was up and running.

Are there others I should include so that the call to get the AD domain name succeeds without throwing an exception?

Comment: Maybe set it as `Delayed Start`?

Comment: Couldn't you just make the AD domain name call every 20 seconds or so until you no longer get an exception, then set an `IsReady` flag and continue running the service?  This would need to be done outside of the `OnStart` method, however.

Comment: @TawabWakil I have a fix already in that if it returns a blank AD domain now, I don't cache it and I don't act on it. But, I was looking for a service dependency that could possibly solve the problem.

Comment: @Charlieface Probably will do that for next release and make it delayed start. Should work for the service.